# Notation in the Semicontinuity Theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

In Hartshorne's book Algebraic Geometry in Chapter III Section 12 we have the following situation:

$f\colon X\to Y$ is a projective morphism of schemes, $Y$ is the affine spectrume of a ring $A$ , and $\mathcal{F}$ is a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, flat over $Y$.
Then he defines for each $A$-module a functor $$T^i(M):=H^i(X,\mathcal{F}\otimes_A M).$$
I do not understand this notation. How is the sheaf $\mathcal{F}\otimes_A M$ defined? How can we tensor $\mathcal{F}$ over $A$ and get a sheaf on $X$?

Comment: I guess $A$ and $R$ should be the same thing, but it seems best to check.  Are they the same?

Comment: Ah yes, thanks.

Comment: I may have answered this at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859708/a-question-about-hartshorne-iii-12-2/859785#859785

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrew notes in comments, he has essentially answered this question.

Just to summarize:

The sheaf $\mathcal F \otimes_A M$ is, by definition, the sheafification
of the presheaf $ U \mapsto \mathcal F(U) \otimes_A M$.

(Here $\mathcal F(U)$ is an $A$-module via the natural "pull-back" map
$A \to \mathcal O_X(X).$)

Equivalently, if we let $\widetilde{M}$ denote the sheaf on $Y = $ Spec $A$
associated to $M$ (so that $\widetilde{M} :=  \mathcal O_Y \otimes_A M$,
where the RHS is defined as above), then $\mathcal F\otimes_A M = \mathcal F \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} f^* \widetilde{M}$.  (Use the standard transitivity property of tensor products.)

Comment: Thank you very much this definitely makes sense. I was just a bit confused since Hartshorne says at the end of the section that he took Mumfords book Abelian Varieties as a reference. There Mumford defines the functor $T^i(M)$ for $A$-algebras $M$ as $H^i(X\times_A M, \mathcal{F}^\prime)$ where $\mathcal{F}^\prime$ is the pulled back sheaf of $\mathcal{F}$ to $X\times_A M$ via the first projection map. Since actually in the end one is only interested in $T^i(k(y))$ in which case both definitions coincide, both ways work.